# Combine files into a single file by date

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with a directory that has a large amount of files that get put in it daily. I'm wondering how I could combine all of the daily files into a single daily file. For example, a file path contains the following files:

```
Name    Date Modified
a.csv   01/01/2020 9:00 AM
b.csv   01/01/2020 10:00 AM
c.csv   01/01/2020 12:00 AM
d.csv   01/03/2020 8:00 AM
e.csv   01/03/2020 11:00 AM
f.csv   01/04/2020 9:00 AM
```

Desired output of files:

```
Name    
combined_01012020.csv 
combined_01032020.csv
combined_01042020.csv
```

Just combining every file for January 1st into one file and so on.
So far I have done this, but it's not what I want:

```
import os
import glob
import time
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'C:\csv_files'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv")

new_csv = list()
for f in files:
    new_csv.append(f)

time = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
new_csv.to_csv(r'C:\daily_csv_files\combined' + str(time)+'.csv', index=False)
```

All this does is combines all files I have into a single file. I've been trying to figure the dates portion of what I want, but haven't had any luck and just combine everything into one large file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you combining by last modified date?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've attempted to do but very unsuccessfully

Comment: I've added a solution but need to expand on it a little got held up, will update soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pathlib and defaultdict

we can iteratively search your directory for csv and then we can create a dictionary with the file as the key and the value is the datetime, we can then reverse engineer this dict to create a single dict with datetime as the key and the file as a list of files. (im sure this could be done in one step but I'm shite with dictionaries)

Note - make sure you make a copy of your files.

set your target path to write your files.

to get the latest modified time we can take adavantage of the `stat` attribute which gives us several bits of information about the file. The one we are interested in is when the file was last modified.

we use `f.stat().st_mtime` on your `Pathlib` object convert it into a datetime and then format the date to match your specified formatting `%m_%d_%y`

```
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

my_path = 'your_dir'

files = [f for f in Path(my_path).glob('*.csv')]
# create a dictionary with file as key and time as value.
file_dict = dict(
    zip(
        files,
        [datetime.fromtimestamp(f.stat().st_mtime).strftime("%m_%d_%y") for f in files],
    )
)

#reverse engineer the list so it has a list appended by the date.

file_merger_list = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in file_dict.items():
    file_merger_list[v].append(k)

# make folder to write to.
target_path = Path(your_path).joinpath('mergedfiles').mkdir(parents=True,exists_ok=False)


for date,file in file_merger_list.items():
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in file])
    df.to_csv(target_path.joinpath(f"combined_{date}.csv"))
```

output

```
 ['combined_01_02_20.csv',
 'combined_01_28_20.csv',
 'combined_12_02_19.csv',
 'combined_12_09_19.csv']
```